# From react-router 3 to 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm pretty new to React and ran in to this issue with a tutorial, where I need to convert react-router from v.3 to v.4. My current code looks like this:

**app.js**

```
<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
```

**routes.js**

```
const routes = {
  component: Base,
  childRoutes: [

    {
      path: '/',
      component: HomePage
    }....
```

**base.js**

```
const Base = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <div className="top-bar">
      <div className="top-bar-left">
        <IndexLink to="/">React App</IndexLink>
      </div>

      <div className="top-bar-right">
        <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
        <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
      </div>

    </div>

    {children}

  </div>
);

Base.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Base;
```

How do I convert this to version 4? I tried with this, but it did not work as expected.

```
 <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by did not work as expected? Were there any errors?

Comment: Hi Mikkel, thanks. Well, I see the frontpage, but without the base.js (menu bar) and when I change the url to /about, I get an "cant get the about page".  So is it possible to abstract the new v.4 router the same way as before. I mean, having a routes.js files with the routes object etc.?

Comment: @KasperGantzhorn Yes this is possible, you just need to extract the routes into a routes object and then use `routes.map` and then map as object as route components. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: @Win I would love an example, thanks!

Comment: @KasperGantzhorn I've added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the example I promised. Pretty self explanatory as I've added comments in the JS. Of course, you can split this out into different files  and etc. but for simplicity sake this example can be quickly rolled in your current project temporary to see how it works. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Make sure you install `React` (*latest* will be fine) and `React-Router 4`.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Link,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom'

// Mock components
const Home = () => <div>Homepage</div>
const About = () => <div>About Page</div>

// This is the routes array, which is
// a index of objects that have a component
// property and a path
const Routes = [
  {
    component: Home,
    path: '/home'
  },
  {
    component: About,
    path: '/about'
  }
]

// This is where we map our routes array
// as a Route component with the properties
// within the object that we created
// ------
// There's a mock navigation bar in here aswell
render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <div>
        <Link to='/home'>Home</Link>
        <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        {Routes.map(route => <Route exact path={route.path} component={route.component} />)}
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Hi Win, thank you for the example, I did not manage to fix the tutorial, but it's my lack of knowledge with React and not your fine example.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a library [react-router-4-compat](https://github.com/vipcxj/react-router-4-compat) to help upgrade from react-router v3 to v4. It work as v3, but based on v4. So it can work with v4 and config as v3. You will not have to change a lot of code to upgrade your project from v3 to v4. This library is still in progress, but will work for most case now.